# Markdown line limit with hyperlink

Tags: markdown, lint, pep8

I am facing issue in markdown file as it says that line exceeds limit.

```
MD013/line-length Line length [Expected: 80; Actual: 181]
```

The line is:

```
Please refer [link](https://github.com/orchestracities/ngsi-timeseries-api/blob/master/docs/manuals/admin/configuration.md#environment-variables) for more info about those variables
```

How can I add hyperlink in limit not crossing `80` as I can not split the hyperlink added above and have to get it within expected length 80.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone out there who's looking for a more general solution. This is what worked for me:

First, make a `.markdownlint.json` file at the root of your project, with the following content:

```
{
  "MD013": {
      "line_length": 80,
      "code_block_line_length": 120
    } 
}
```

You could now set your line length to be whatever you prefer!

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a reference style link. Reference style links are not limited by the linter's line length rule. They are also much easier to read/edit later on.

```
Please refer [link][1] for more info about those variables 

[1]: https://github.com/orchestracities/ngsi-timeseries-api/blob/master/docs/manuals/admin/configuration.md#environment-variables
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Please can u also let me know how to limit `[1]: https://github.com/orchestracities/ngsi-timeseries-api/blob/master/docs/manuals/admin/configuration.md#environment-variables` within 79 character....or any way of that too as code linter will fail for this statement.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, a Markdown linter should not run line length against the reference link. If it is, then that is a bug in the linter.

Comment: This answer should get accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem(but there was also a bug fix: MD033/no-inline-html: Inline HTML), but none of the answers helped. I followed the solution by borna-tavasoli: writing the values 80 and 120 gave an error - the bool type was required) It helped me to write:

```
{
    "MD033": {
        "allowed_elements": ["details" , "summary"]
    },
    "line_length": false,
    "code_block_line_length": false
}
```